# Java Heap size Memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have a Java application, which is throwing Java Heap size Memory error. My application is about converting a file into .csv format and load it into DB. When the File content is less my application is working good. But when i have hundreds of thousands of records i am getting heap size memory. What all possibilities for memory leak to happen when using classes like InputStream, OutputStream, BufferedWriter etc., Please help me to resolve this Heap size memory error. I am stuck with it for a week. Given below is the Heap size error i get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Can you provide some code of your application?

Answer (score 4):

So, you're reading the whole file into the memory and then flush it to DB.

Instead of doing that you need to read chunks of file into memory and flush them into DB.

It's impossible to give a more detailed answer without the code.

Comment: While converting the file into .csv format i do it as a whole but while uploading the records into DB i am not loading the record as a whole into the DB. I load it batch by batch.

Answer (score 1):

when you run the file you need to add -Xmx## to the command line.

```
java -Xmx4G
```

would give you a JVM with 4 Gb available.

EDIT: if possible you should load one bit at a time like @Oleg mentioned.

Comment: I apologize, i am not clear about increasing the heap size memory. My question is, whenever i am running the application, i have to increase the heap size before i run the application with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to increase heap size , you can use `java -Xmx2048m` in command line.

you will have up to 2GB memory now.

Follow this link for [more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html#nonstandard)

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the heap size.

If you can share your code, i could tell you in what ways you can reduce the resource utilization